# How to get Dash to work with a Choropleth Plotly graph

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to get a Ploty choropleth map to display using Dash. I've tried updating Dash and Plotly by using the `conda update --all` and `conda update dash` in the anaconda prompt, but this hasn't fixed the issue. Below are links for the images of what the code produces for the `fig.show()` code and the Dash code.

[image]

Dash plotly graph that won't work:

[image]

Below is the code:

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


fig = px.choropleth(dt_rwly_stn, geojson=smh, color="ConfirmedCovidCases",
                    locations="CountyName", featureidkey="properties.CountyName",
                    projection="mercator",
                    color_continuous_scale= 'Reds',
                   )
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show() 

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='My First Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph1',
        figure=fig
    ),
])
                 
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Can anyone help me get the Plotly figure to display correctly using Dash?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I had to uninstall Anaconda as I had too many conflicting packages installed on my base environment. When I reinstalled it I made a new environment and only installed the packages I needed (i.e `conda install -c conda-forge dash` and `conda install -c conda-forge plotly` . The code in question now works perfectly.

[Dash Plotly Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic9WY.png)